# C++ thread error: no type named ‘type’

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

i know that this topic was asked a lot of time but I don't understand where is the error in my code.

I have a foo.h file where I have defined:

```
class Foo {
    public:
       Foo();
       ~Foo();
       void DoSomething(cv::Mat& img);
       void DoSomethingAsync(cv::Mat& img);

    private:
       bool isFinished = false;
};
```

then a foo.cpp like this:

```
Foo:Foo() {}

Foo:~Foo() {}

void Foo::DoSomethingAsync(cv::Mat& img) {
try {
    IsFinished = true;
} catch(exception& e) {
}   

void Foo::DoSomething(cv::Mat& img) {
 thread_mutex.lock();
 thread_async = std::move(std::thread(&Foo::DoSomethingAsync, this, img));
thread_mutex.unlock();
}
```

from my main.cpp file I call the function:

```
Foo foo;
foo.DoSomething(im);
```

when I compile, I always obtain this error:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (ObjectDetector::*)(cv::Mat&)>(ObjectDetector*, cv::Mat)>’
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (ObjectDetector::*)(cv::Mat&)>(ObjectDetector*, cv::Mat)>’
     _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

Could you explain me why?

in my CMake I set the variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS with -pthread

Comment: What is `thread_async`? What is the `Detect` function? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Your example does not contain the names of types that your error contains. And, what further increases the doubts that it isn't a real example: you have `foo.Detect(im);` method call, while `Detect` isn't defined in `Foo`.

Comment: @alexmark Be careful that asking questions and deleting them repetitively may lead to banning you from asking questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: sorry @TheQuantumPhysicist I tried to adjust my question preparing a better code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite the fact that you still didn't manage to provide a MCVE, I managed to decipher your issue. You need to use `std::ref` while passing `img`:

```
std::thread(&Foo::DoSomethingAsync, this, std::ref(img));
```

The reasoning becomes obvious when you read [`std::thread::thread`'s documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) - you should have done this before posting on StackOverflow.

> 3) Creates new `std::thread` object and associates it with a thread of execution. The new thread of execution starts executing
>
> > ```
> > std::invoke(decay_copy(std::forward<Function>(f)), 
> >             decay_copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
> > ```

[**live example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xsQdA5zkkcLQmI48) *(please create one yourself demostrating the error in the future!)*

---

Also:

- You're using `std::move` on an *rvalue*. This is wrong, as it is unnecessary and prevents *copy elision*.
- Just use a *lambda expression* to initialize your `std::thread` - it will be easier to read and have less surprising behavior.